# Updating a variable in visual C# code for usage in calculations and display on web form

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm writing a simple C# code to calculate the GPA of a user given a group of their classes. All of the classes are weighted to 3 credits, and they select their grade via a dropdownlist, containing items from A to F, each list item with its own value based on a standard GPA grading scheme.

The problem I've run into is updating a variable I've created for the purpose of keeping track of the sum of the user's GPA from all of their classes, for the purpose of displaying this number to them and dividing this number by the number of courses they have for the purpose of obtaining an average, accurate to two decimal points.

No matter what I do, the value will not update (noted within the custom method of `GPACarrier()`) and only carries the most recently input value in itself, rather than adding any newly input values to the sum. For example, if the user is to note two classes, one with an A and the other with a B, instead of the GPA sum variable containing 7.00, it will only contain the last GPA value that the user input, so if they input the B last, the GPA sum variable will only read 3.00.

I've attempted to move the computation out of the original method it existed in, making its own custom method, and changing how the code is written, but I may have run into a logic jam in my brain, because I cannot think of any other solutions, other than a minor syntax error that would be causing this problem.

```cs
protected decimal GPAAverage;
protected decimal ValueSum;
protected decimal GPASum = 0.00m;
protected decimal ValueOutput;
protected decimal GPATempValue = 0.00m;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void GPACarrier(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GPATempValue = Convert.ToDecimal(LetterGradeList.SelectedValue);
    GPASum += GPATempValue;
}
protected void ContinueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StudentInformationLabel.Text = LastNameBox.Text + ", " + FirstNameBox.Text + " (" + MajorList.SelectedValue + ")";
    GPACalculatePage.Visible = true;
    StudentInformationPage.Visible = false;
}
protected void AddCourseLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddClassPanel.Visible = true;
}
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GPACarrier(sender, e);
    String NewCourse = PrefixBox.Text + " " + CourseNumberBox.Text + " " + "(" + LetterGradeList.SelectedItem.Text + ")";
    CourseHistoryList.Items.Add(new ListItem(NewCourse, LetterGradeList.SelectedValue));
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(GPATempValue);
    AddClassPanel.Visible = false;
    PrefixBox.Text = " ";
    CourseNumberBox.Text = " ";
    LetterGradeList.ClearSelection();
}
```

Comment: this line is the problem `Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(GPATempValue);` you use `GPATempValue`  insted of  `GPASum`

Comment: This issue could have been easily resolved yourself by simply using the debugger, which you should always do before posting a question here anyway. If you don't know how to use the debugger, stop what you're doing and learn now. It will save you lots of wasted time.